# WPF: Restarting storyboards with datatriggers / boolean values?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a DataTrigger that runs a storyboard based on a boolean value

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsValid}" Value="True">
  <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
       <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard>
                 ...                                
              </Storyboard>
       </BeginStoryboard>
  </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

So when IsValid = true, then my storyboard runs. This works okay. But here's the issue:
I'd like my storyboard to RERUN when my IsValid = true. My IsValid looks like this:

```
private bool _isValid = false;
public bool IsValid
{
      set {
      _isValid = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("IsValid")
      }
}
```

I know my storyboard is bound to it being true, but isn't there a way to restart the darn thing and have the storyboard restart each time I go IsValid = true in my ViewModel code?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your storyboard is never stopped. You need to give your `BeginStoryboard` a name, and add an `ExitActions` section:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsValid}" Value="True">
  <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
       <BeginStoryboard Name="sb">
              <Storyboard>
                 ...                                
              </Storyboard>
       </BeginStoryboard>
  </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
  <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
       <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="sb" />
  </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Didn't know about StopStoryBoard, solved my DataTrigger problem. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this was doing:

```
 IsValid = false; // this needs to come right before i ever do an IsValid = true
 IsValid = true;
```

Then the animation restarts auto-magically, brilliant eh?

Answer (score 1):

So I had the issue of "restarting" an animation. storyboard.remove or storyboard.stop won't work as I want for some reason.

anyway, I searched for a while, and when I found out there's no solution, I realised I had the same issue a few years ago, and my homemade solution is as follows: Simply add a keyframe at time 0 with all the properties reset.

Example in code, vb .net:

```
Dim sb As New Storyboard
        Dim dauk3 As New DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
        dauk3.BeginTime = New TimeSpan(0)
        dauk3.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, target)
        dauk3.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, New PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)"))

'The keyframe below resets the animation at time 0
        Dim sdk0 As New SplineDoubleKeyFrame()
        sdk0.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)
        sdk0.Value = 0
'The keyframe above resets the animation at time 0

        Dim sdk As New SplineDoubleKeyFrame()
        sdk.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(span)
        sdk.Value = width

        dauk3.KeyFrames.Add(sdk0)
        dauk3.KeyFrames.Add(sdk)
        sb.Children.Add(dauk3)
        sb.Begin(Me, True)
```

Example, in design, xaml:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="Show GridIconDetailsRight">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="GridIconDetailsRight">

<!-- The keyframe below resets value at time 0 -->
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
<!-- The keyframe above resets value at time 0 -->

                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="-200"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
         </Storyboard>
```

Hope this helps people out. I was pulling my hair all day when I remembered my solution.